# htaccess redirecting all urls except one to a different domain not working

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I'm trying to redirect all urls **except** http://shop.mysite.com/enquiry/ to a different domain like below but it's redirecting everything to "example.com", including the "enquiry" page.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/enquiry/
RewriteRule .* https://www.example.com [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}/index.html !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}/index.php !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php
</IfModule>
```

So how do I make sure "enquiry" isn't redirected?

Answer (score 1):

For a negative condition, you should `THE_REQUEST` variable instead of `REQUEST_URI`:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !/enquiry[?\s/] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.example.com [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}/index.html !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}/index.php !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

`THE_REQUEST` variable represents original request received by Apache from your browser and it **doesn't get overwritten** after execution of some rewrite rules. Example value of this variable is `GET /index.php?id=123 HTTP/1.1`

Make sure to clear your browser cache or use a new browser when testing.

Comment: I copied and pasted your entire code but unfortunately that still doesn't resolve the issue. Still redirecting everything. I cleared cache and used different browser. Btw, your code has an error at `{NC]`.

Comment: It should not redirect a URL that **starts** with `/enquiry/`. Make sure to test with only these 2 rules in your .htaccess. Does your URL have something before `/enquiry/` also?

Comment: I have also made a minor change in my rule, test with these now.

Comment: Yes that seems to work. However I didn't need the line `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^shop\. [NC]`. I also used `!/enquiry/?` instead of `!/enquiry/`.

Answer (score 1):

Your final RewriteRule for index.php is probably causing an additional redirect to occur in the PHP script.

You could try moving the redirect below this rule:

`<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}/index.html !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}/index.php !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/enquiry/?
    RewriteRule .* https://www.example.com [R=301,L]
</IfModule>`

In addition, you will need to add some more rewrite conditions to exclude referenced scripts/stylesheets from being redirected too.

Comment: Thanks for some useful tips! You are right about the rewrite conditions to exclude scripts and stylesheets.